# Power BI Creating sort of snapshot of a table everyday after synch

Tags: powerbi

I have a question about power BI.

I connected Power BI with a CRM System where I get mostly data about Deals. This data is only as of today. In my power bi data model, I have created a new table "Table" with dates from 1.11.24 until 31.12.30 each row being a new date. In the table deal, I have also a new column which gets me the Date today every day.

Now coming to the problem that I need to fix. The solution should be ideally this. The new table "Table" should have aggregated the sum of all "Opportunities" from table deal every day and write to the corresponding date under the column "Total Revenue". Let's today 7.11.23, there should be 200 in table "Table". Tomorrow a new deal is created worth of 20 euros, so for 8.11.23 it should be 220. And so on. How can I do it?

I have this table:
Table = CALENDAR(DATE(2023, 11, 01), DATE(2030, 12, 31))

Total Revenue =
CALCULATE(
SUM('crm_deal'[OPPORTUNITY]),
FILTER(
'crm_deal',
'crm_deal'[Heute] = Datumstabelle[Date].[Date]
)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it in Power BI alone. You will need to store each day's data somewhere.

Here is one approach.

1. Power Automate script, running daily, queries your PBI dataset to get today's number, and adds it as a new row in Excel which is on SharePoint/OneDrive.
2. Power BI imports this new table from Excel.

Comment: Let me know if you need more on the above. If happy, please accept the answer for the benefit of all.